# Can I rely on jQuery's load method to preserve "application/json" type script tags when called without a selector as argument?

Tags: jquery

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() **prior to scripts being removed**. This executes the script blocks **before they are discarded**. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

While the paragraph above is true in both cases for javascript script tags, I have observed that script tags that have a "application/json" type, such as:

```
<script type="application/json">
    {hello: "world"}
</script>
```

Will *not* get discarded after parsing when only a URL is specified (that is, with no specific selector). This is convenient because the json data can be fetched without a problem afterwards in these cases.

My question is, is this a known intentional behaviour that I can rely on? I'm asking because I don't see this feature officially documented anywhere, thus I'm not sure if it's a good idea to build upon it.

Comment: "When called without a selector"..? That aside, have you tried and if so what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @NigelAngel There are two ways the load method can be called to fetch html via ajax. One is passing the URL and the selector you want to load, the other is passing a URL alone. I'm talking about the second case.

Comment: Not sure it's something to rely on as it should technically clear it the same way it does with other scripts so it may be flag as a defect in the future and fix in a future release which would break code dependent on that.

Comment: @gillesc I figured this could be the case, hence why I'm asking, I was hoping someone would know for sure what's going on here.